# Binding image using converter in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I'm developing Windows phone apps using VS2012 and C#(Windows 8.0 SDK) and I'm new to it, I'm using the below code to bind PNG image using `Converter`

```xml
xmlns:myproject="clr-namespace:SolutionName.Converters"

 <UserControl.Resources>
    <myproject:LoginHistoryImageConverter x:Key="LoginHistoryImageConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource pivotBackground}">
        <ListBox x:Name="listBoxLogs">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid MinWidth="480" Height="88" Margin="12,0,12,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Image Width="80" Height="80" Source="{Binding device, Converter={StaticResource LoginHistoryImageConverter}}"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="85,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="{Binding date}" Foreground="{StaticResource MessageListForeground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="{Binding ip_address}" Foreground="{StaticResource MessageListForeground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MaxWidth="200"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,38,0">
                            <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding time}" Foreground="{StaticResource MessageListForeground}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding location}" Foreground="{StaticResource MessageListForeground}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MaxWidth="200"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

you can observe I'm binding image

```
<Image Width="80" Height="80" Source="{Binding device, Converter={StaticResource LoginHistoryImageConverter}}"/>
```

I'm getting `device` as string "M" or "PC", by using converter, I returned `BitmapImage`

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
        String text = (String)value;                        
        if (text.Equals("M"))
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Assets/mobile.png",UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
            return new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/Assets/pc.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
 }
```

when i get string `"M"` i need to display `mobile` image else `PC` image
But when i navigate to my page it fires an `XamlParseException` at `"InitializeComponent()"`, Please observe image
[image]

Even i tried below code for binding image, but no luck

```
<Image Width="80" Height="80">
    <Image.Source>
        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding device, Converter={StaticResource LoginHistoryImageConverter}}"/>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

Did I miss something. Please help me

Full XAML Code

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="SampleProject.Views.Settings.Logs.LoginHistory"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:myproject="clr-namespace:SampleProject.Converters"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <myproject:LoginHistoryImageConverter x:Key="LoginHistoryImageConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

        <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource pivotBackground}">
        <ListBox x:Name="listBoxLogs">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid MinWidth="480" Height="88" Margin="12,0,12,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Image Width="80" Height="80" Source="{Binding device, Converter={StaticResource LoginHistoryImageConverter}}"/>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="85,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="{Binding date}" Foreground="{StaticResource MessageListForeground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="25" Text="{Binding ip_address}" Foreground="{StaticResource MessageListForeground}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MaxWidth="200"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,38,0">
                            <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding time}" Foreground="{StaticResource MessageListForeground}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="18" Text="{Binding location}" Foreground="{StaticResource MessageListForeground}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MaxWidth="200"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there's a few issues in the XAML code you provided. The `pivotBackground` and `MessageListForeground` resources aren't defined but maybe you defined them at a global level, for instance in the `App.xaml`, in which case it should fine.

Otherwise, your code should work. You can get more information on the precise cause of failure by checking the details of the exception: when the exception occurs, like you showed in your screenshot, click on "View details", then expand and check the value of the `Message` and `InnerException` properties:

[image]

Comment: Sorry KooKiz, i edit question now, Actually I'm referencing same converter. but didn't work out

Comment: KooKiz, I'm facing same issue with below code, it is simple slider code
        <Slider Height="84" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="45,51,0,0" Name="slider1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="369" Minimum="10" Maximum="100" Value="30" SmallChange="10" LargeChange="20"/>
        <TextBlock Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="107,141,0,0" Name="textBox1" Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=slider1}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
but when i add Converter = {StaticResource RoundOffConverter} on textblock it throws same exception, where RoundOffConverter is Math.round(value)

Comment: KooKiz, I had edited my question with full xaml code, Please check it

Comment: @RajkumarMandera Edited my answer, I hope that helps

Comment: Yes, I defined MessageListForeground and pivotBackground  at global level in App.xaml, they are loading fine no problem with them.
I'll check InnerException properties. Thanks KooKiz

Comment: On InnerExcetion details, "Message" says "Cannot create instance of type 'SampleProject.Converters.RoundOffConverter' [Line: 19 Position: 44]", I cannot figure this out why it cannot create an instance. do you have any idea, please help me

Comment: @RajkumarMandera When you declare the converter in the resources, it has to create an instance to use it. As to know why creating an instance fails... Maybe there's something wrong in the constructor? I guess you'll have to add the code of your converter as well ;)

Comment: I tried the same code in VS 2010 with windows phone 7.1 SDK its working fine, what is problem with VS2012 with windows phone 8.0 SDK, where my other converters are working fine.